# Your app includes non compliant SDK version

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

Your app version code 2 includes SDK com.flurry.android:analytics or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Android ID, Advertising ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

--

Starting from January 23, 2023 midnight (UTC), new app releases containing the SDK version(s) that do not comply with the User Data policy may be blocked from release. You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code if available from your SDK provider, or removing this SDK from your app

--

I have used both the version (14.0.0 and 14.2.0) but I still getting the non compliant message when deploying

Comment: Just guessing but 14.1.0 and therefore also 14.2.0 look like they should address this, maybe you either did not actually install a newer version (`flutter pub upgrade` I think) or somehow the android build decided to use an old cached version or you uploaded the wrong file?

Comment: I updated the API thru project structure-dependencies.  Invalidated the Cache, but still I get the same non compliant message from google when deploying

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your projects do use Flurry SDK 14.#.# or above. To see the full dependencies, please try to run `"gradlew dependencies"` under your project's app folder. Example of output,

```
...
+--- com.flurry.android:analytics:14.2.0
+--- com.flurry.android:marketing:14.2.0
|    \--- com.flurry.android:analytics:14.2.0
...
```